# fixed float right div, but different stacked order with media query

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I have two divs,

```
<div class="right"></div> 
<div class="left"></div>
```

In that order. For those wondering why I have ordered the HTML elements as such, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8094787/fixed-width-div-on-right-fill-remaining-width-div-on-left) question. The right div is of a fixed width along with the CSS property; `float:right;`
So when the page is resized, the left div expands to take up the rest of the page.

However, at a certain width, I want both divs to be 100% wide, but stacked such that the right div is **below** the left div.

I realise this is to do with the ordering of the html elements, but is there a way to make this work? I tried the solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19073130/have-a-fixed-width-right-floated-div-drop-below-other-content) thread, but it doesn't seem to work.

I have a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/EXn6Z/).

**EDIT:**

Ok, so I discovered the answer. I was missing a parent **container** div which needed `display:table;` Now it works beautifully.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="right"></div>
<div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .container {
     display:table;
}
```

(Although I can't get it to work in the fiddle...)

So here is a CSS only solution if anyone needs it in future.

Comment: Is there a lot of content inside of the .right div? If not you can just add another .right after the .left, show/hide it when needed in your media query

Comment: Have you tried taking a look at Bootstrap's pull and push classes? You might be able to gain some inspiration from those: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: Let me know if my solution suits you. There is always more than one way to implement anything. :)

Comment: @BootstrapThemer, nope, the goal is to have the div which is **first** show up second. You just switched the two divs.

Comment: @jcaron I don't see why BootstrapThemer's solution doesn't solve the problem. It would seem that myol's problem only occurs because of the order which the elements were placed. Unless there was a specific reason why reordering the elements isn't possible, BootstrapThemer's answer looks legit. Why invent some convoluted answer to a problem that could easily be avoided?

Comment: @Jason, the whole point of the question is to be able to change the order the divs are displayed. The OP might not have any control over the HTML generation but only the CSS. If you can reorder the divs, the answer is of course trivial.

Comment: Yes, but he can since the first answer requires a .main wrapper. Plus, why in the html would you have the stuff that least important first?

Comment: @jcaron as BootstrapThemer pointed out, the OP clearly has control over the HTML generated because he is able to place a wrapper around the divs. Also, if we were to follow the strict directions given by the OP (as you suggested), my answer would be the only legit one that doesn't involve `display:table` hacks.

Comment: @BootstrapThemer: the wrapping container may already be there. In the worst case, it's the body. The flex box solutions as well as mine do also work while actually answering the OP's question.

Comment: I have edited the question to inform people why I ordered the HTML elements that way. I used that method because I want to support IE and mobile browsers. The CSS calc property is not yet widely supported on mobile.

Comment: @myol : I realized, on the second go at the answer, that the 100% fluid/fixed was the reason why you had that div order. With content-box sizing, that was the way to do it. My answer didn't use flexbox, display:table, or calc, transforms, it used box-sizing:border-box and a negative margin, supported stuff in IE8 and current browsers. Plus, the more important content is first in the html, not for SEO but for logic, though these days, hardly anyone cares about that. http://jsbin.com/cizox/1/edit  http://media.crossbrowsertesting.com/users/50267/snapshots/z65acffb9385ce671df4.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `display: table` property. This does not support borders though

DEMO http://jsfiddle.net/EXn6Z/12/

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .main {
        display: table;
    }
    .right {
        display: table-footer-group;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .left {
        display: table-header-group;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yea, I discovered this after I posted the question. You got the fiddle to work too so +1. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to use `transform: scaleY(-1);` and a wrapper.

Try with this code if it suits your needs:

**HTML**

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="right"></div> 
<div class="left"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed blue;    
}

.right {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .right {       
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .left {       
        float: left;
        width: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper{
        width:100%;
        position: absolute;
        float: left;
        -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
        transform: scaleY(-1);
    }
    div.wrapper > div {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    display: block;
    min-height: 50px;
    -webkit-transform: scaleY(-1);
    transform: scaleY(-1);
    }

}
```

Ps. I changed the rgb values to red and blue for better readability.

Check this DEMO:

http://jsfiddle.net/EXn6Z/11/

Answer (score 1):

You can (ab)use the power of `display: table-caption` to make an element appear above others even if it comes after in your HTML code though the other element must have `display: table-row` here thus no border or background on it and you'd have to add an extra div if you want a background or border on `.left`.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdbcB

Relevant CSS (MQ):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .right {
    display: table-row;
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .left {
    display: table-caption;
    overflow: visible;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

---

If you can add a parent div with `display: table` then you don't have to force `display: table-row` on `div.right` (better option imho). This is due to *anonymous boxes* created by browsers when the perfect serie of 3 elements `table > row > cell` isn't exactly there... Complex stuff.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eIfmn

HTML:

```
<div class="table-like">
  <div class="right">On right or below Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Architecto error maiores quos incidunt quaerat atque amet perspiciatis ad quae maxime, possimus tempore rerum laudantium, fugit laborum sint consequatur eveniet veniam?</div> 
  <div class="left">On left or above</div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS (MQ):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .table-like {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .right {
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 0;
  }
  .left {
    display: table-caption;
    overflow: visible;
    width: auto;
  }
}
```

---

Even if these 2 options work, it causes problems and I'd advise you against using them except if really really you don't have any other choice (like complex layout on desktop and tablet and now comes mobile resolution - in *desktop first* - and your HTML order is already set or your client won't let change HTML)

Problem that is accessibility related: WCAG 2.0 Technique H4: [Creating a logical tab order through links, form controls, and objects](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG20-TECHS/H4.html)

Answer (score 0):

You might not like this one because it involves jQuery, but overall it's pretty simple:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() <= 600) {
        $('.right').before($('.left'));
    } else {
        $('.right').after($('.left'));
    }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LimitedWard/6ZE3B/

This technique avoids having unnecessary/duplicate elements.

This technique is also not a hack (unlike other answers that use `display:table`).

Note: there are ways of making this more efficient, but this should get the job done just fine.

Comment: One benefit of this method is that it actually moves the element within the HTML rather than moving it using some positioning hacks. This means that if the user tries highlighting text in both divs, the highlight occurs in the correct order.

Answer (score 0):

If the two divs are alone in a container (which may be `body`), then it's just a matter of sticking the first `div` to the bottom (using `position: absolute` and `bottom: 0`) and adding a `margin-bottom` to the second `div`. All of this in the relevant media-query section of course.

Caveat: if both `div`s have a variable height it might be quite a bit more difficult.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div id="right">nav</div>
  <div id="left">content</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
*
{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#container
{
    border: solid 2px green;
}
#left
{
    border: solid 2px red;
    min-height: 50px;
}

#right
{
    border: solid 2px blue;
    min-height: 50px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px)
{
    #left
    {
        margin-right: 200px;
    }
    #right
    {
        float: right;
        width: 200px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 599px)
{
    #container
    {
        position: relative;
    }
    #left
    {
        margin-bottom: 50px;
    }
    #right
    {
        position: absolute;
        width: 100%;
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zqDN7/

Comment: Can someone explain the down vote? AFAIK, this solution answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Flexbox** layout can be horizontal or **vertical** and will let you rearrange the order of children of a container at will.

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FnLhu

HTML:

```
<div class="small-flex small-flex-v">
  <div class="right small-ml0 small-wauto">On right or below</div> 
  <div class="left small-flex-start">On left or above</div>
</div>
```

Relevant CSS (MQ with classes prefixed by `.small-`):

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  .small-flex {
    display : -webkit-box;
    display : -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display : -webkit-flex;
    display : flex;
  }
  .small-flex-v {
    -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
    -moz-box-orient: vertical;
    -webkit-flex-direction: column;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .small-flex-start {
    -webkit-box-ordinal-group: -1;
    -moz-box-ordinal-group: 0;
    -ms-flex-order : -1;
    -webkit-order : -1;
    -moz-order : -1;
    order : -1;
  }
}
```

This is my second answer to this question, with no `table-caption` *trick*.
Advantage over `display: table-caption` or @Victor's solution with `table-*-group`: no problem with borders and/or backgrounds on these elements
Drawback: compatibility is IE9+ when `display: table-*` is IE8+

Answer (score 0):

This is a solution with `display: flex` usage:

```
.wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.left {
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f;
    order: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;

}

.right {
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f;
    order: 2;
    width: 200px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
   .right,
   .left {
    flex: 1 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
}
```

for a markup like this:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="right">right</div>
  <div class="left">left</div>
</div>
```

An example: http://jsfiddle.net/RVk9Q/1/

Don't forget to use the needed prefixes

Answer (score -1):

Add another `div` where you need it and then use the `display` to hide/show the correct one.

HTML:

```
<div class="right-large"></div> 
<div class="left"></div>
<div class="right-mobile"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.left {
    overflow: hidden;
    min-height: 50px;
    border: 2px dashed #f0f
}

.right-large, .right-mobile {
    float: right;
    width: 250px;
    min-height: 50px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: 2px dashed #00f
}

.right-mobile{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .right-large{
        display: none;
    }
    .right-mobile {
        display: block;
        float: right;
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/EXn6Z/7/)**